# Run jQuery Event on divs with same class only once per div

Tags: jquery

I have non-editable HTML (a third-party platform) that I am customizing. I'm trying to move the div with a class ".IDX-showcasePrice" in each ".IDX-showcaseCell", however when I execute the code below, it pulls all of the divs with class ".IDX-showcasePrice" and inserts them into each parent div.

Is there a way to isolate each div one by one and have it execute only on that div?

I apologize for the HTML screenshot, but there is no access to the source code.

[Screenshot of HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/31c1E.png)

```
<script>
 (function() {
  $('.IDX-showcaseCell').each(function() {
   $(this).siblings('.IDX-showcasePrice').insertBefore('.IDX-
   showcaseAddress');
  });
 })(jQuery);
</script>
```

Comment: Why did you use `siblings`? Your `IDX-showcasePrice`s are **inside** `IDX-showcaseCell`. Shouldn't you use `children`?

Comment: UPDATE: I've made the change to children() but still no success. With that change, there is nothing happening...

Comment: It should be `.before()` not insertBefore if you want to use insertBefore you need to convert it to domElement not jQuery DOM elementry.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in the comments, `siblings` is not the correct function, since `IDX-showcasePrice` are **inside** `IDX-showcaseCell`, not at same level. But inside is a little vague, we have to consider how deep your `IDX-showcasePrice` are inside `IDX-showcaseCell`(second level in this case).

documentation about `children`:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .children() method allows us to search through the children of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements. The .children() method differs from .find() in that .children() only travels a **single level down** the DOM tree while .find() can traverse down multiple levels to select descendant elements (grandchildren, etc.) as well.

Just here you can find the answer: when you try using `children` you get only first level children, not second level.